# Error message when trying to install driver on Appium cli

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

I've recently installed the Appium cli executing the command found on the official documentation:

```
 npm install -g appium
```

When the installation ended successfully, I've tried to install the UI Automator 2 driver on it by using the following command, as described in the official documentation (https://appium.github.io/appium/docs/en/2.0/quickstart/uiauto2-driver/):

```
 appium driver install uiautomator2
```

Although I've executed this command, I get the following message:

```
 usage: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js [-h] [--shell] [--allow-cors] [--reboot] [--ipa IPA] [-a ADDRESS] [...and so on]

 C:\Users\alessandrov\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js: error: unrecognized arguments: driver install uiautomator2
```

I have configured ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME and the Jdk, in fact I already use UI Automator 2 in an Android project, but still not with Appium.

What am I doing wrong? Is it the only way to install it?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me as well, in my case I had an old version of Appium (1.16) and it happens when you install it with : *npm install -g appium*

Use **npm install -g appium@next** to install v 2.0 and try again with installing a driver

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and it turned out corporate network policy was blocking some component (I believe it was the chromedriver portion).

It took me a couple of days to figure this out, but once I got out from behind the corporate firewall I was able to install successfully.

Not sure if that's the same issue you're having, but I hope it helps.